# sequence of real numbers with a specific property

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Below is the question and a proof, but the proof seems flawed.
> [image]

> I want to understand this proof better, so I have the following questions:

- $\cup_{k=m}^\infty [a^k, b^k - \frac{1}2]$ equals $[a^m , \infty)$. Because the intervals overlap, right?
- Is the claim "Since the decreasing intervals $I_1\supset I_2\cdots$ are nonempty, closed and bounded, their intersection is nonempty" correct?

Comment: *Consider* $X = \mathbb{N}$ *with the discrete metric, and* $\ldots$ --- What does $X = \mathbb N$ and the discrete metric have to do with the result you're asking about? That result is for the real numbers with the usual metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, we do have $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=m}^\infty\left[a^k,b^k-\frac12\right]$ might not equal $[a^m,\infty)$. That's because of the fact the intervals $\left[a^k,b^k-\frac12\right]$ and $\left[a^{k+1},b^{k+1}-\frac12\right]$ overlap.
- This is true because we have the [nested intervals theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals#Theorem): a sequence of nested non-empty closed and bounded intervals is always non-empty.

And the whole proof looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks. Could you prove that the intervals are indeed nested?

Comment: Sure. You have $I_{j-1}=[a,b]$ and then $n_j$ is such that it belongs to $\left[a^{k_j},b^{k_j}-\frac12\right]$. Therefore $\sqrt[k_j]{n_j}\geqslant a$ and $\sqrt[k_j]{n_j+\frac12}\leqslant b$. So,$$I_j=\left[\sqrt[k_j]{n_j},\sqrt[k_j]{n_j+\frac12}\right]\subset[a,b]=I_{j-1}.$$

Comment: Actually, that hypothesis about $\operatorname{diam}(I_j)<\varepsilon$ is only needed when we are trying to prove that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}I_n$ consists of a single point. It is *not* needed if the goal is to prove that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}I_n\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: Yes, but does that hypothesis hold? When I mentioned "nested intervals" it was implicit in my definition that diam($I_j) < \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $j$.

Comment: And why should I care about your definition of “nested intervals”? What matters is the standard meaning of that expression.

Comment: Which false information have I provided?

Comment: See the following definition of nested intervals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134435/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-fred-jefferson).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question: In the discrete metric, closed and bounded sets are not necessarily compact, so the intersection is not necessarily nonempty. But in your proof the usual topology is used, where a closed and bounded set is compact (Heine-Borel theorem), so one may conclude nonempty intersection of nested closed (nonempty) intervals. Compacity is the key.